# Find the general Solution of Second order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

find the general solution of $$x^2y''-(2x+2x^2)y'+(x^2+2x+2)y=0$$

**My Approach**

Let $xu(x)=2y$, which reduces the above equation to $$ u''-2u'+u=0$$

The solution for which is: $u(x)=(c_1+xc_2)e^x$ $\implies 2y=x(c_1+xc_2)e^x$

I would like to know if I am going in the right direction or not.

Comment: Factor 2 is not ,needed especially in the end with the constants. Thats correct. But $ux=y$ works fine too